# C++ - Why does 2 local references to the same object stay in sync?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, reference, variable-assignment

I would like to understand what's going on here. Obviously, there's some aspect of references or assignment operators that I am not getting right.

**Objective**: Within a function, I want to work with 2 local reference variables to various elements of the same list: one is the iterated over and one is a "marker" that changes when certain conditions are met. Both are initially referencing the same element. I'm not modifying the strings in the list (in the actual code, the list is a parameter passed by reference).

**Problem**: as soon as a change the second reference to another element, the first reference now points to that new element as well. The references stay in sync, but I expected them to be independent.

**My interpretation**: iterator is a pointer to a string that is contained in the list. In `string & ref1 = *it`, I am dereferencing iterator pointer to get the string address (whether that itself is a pointer shouldn't really matter IMO) so that `ref1` and `ref2` are "aliases" to the address of string "a". So in my mind, changing ref2 so it points to another string does not change the address of anything, but just the value of ref2 should now point or "alias" to string "b", while ref1 should still points to "a".

Changing the code to use pointers instead of references works perfectly, so it seems I am incorrectly treating reference variables as pointers, or there's something behind the scenes (overloaded assignment operators?) I'm not thinking of.

```
list<string> l;    
string s1 = "a";   
string s2 = "b";    
l.push_back(s1);    
l.push_back(s2);    
list<string>::iterator it = l.begin();    
string & ref1 = *it;    
string & ref2 = *it;    
++it;    // After this line, both ref1 && ref2 evaluates to "a"
ref2 = *it; // After this line, both ref1 && ref2 evaluates to "b"
if(ref1 == ref2){    
  cout << "woot!" << endl;    
}
```

Comment: reference variables are just an alias for the original variable. In contrast to pointers you cannot change the variable a reference is referencing

Comment: References are an alias to another value. You can think of it as a pointer without the added syntax. So anytime you change the original value, all references to that object change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string & ref1 = *it;    
string & ref2 = *it;
```

Okay, so you create two references to the same string.

```
++it;    // After this line, both ref1 && ref2 evaluates to "a"
```

Right, because they are both references to the same string. This is the way you created them.

```
ref2 = *it; // After this line, both ref1 && ref2 evaluates to "b"
```

Right, because they are both references to the same string, and you just used one to change the value of the string it referred to.

> So in my mind, changing ref2 so it points to another string does not change the address of anything, but just the value of ref2 should now point or "alias" to string "b", while ref1 should still points to "a".

That's not how references work. This is how references work:

```
int a, b;
int& ref = a;
ref = b; // same as a=b, does not "re-seat" the reference
```

If you want a reference that can be "re-seated", use [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: Are you saying that I modified the original strings? I totally missed that.

Comment: Yes, you used a reference to them to change their values.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, if not using a wrapper (which I assume uses pointers), must I use pointers to do this task without copying the strings to regular variables?

Comment: @mtone Pointers are probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is similar to a pointer where you can't change the address that it points to. Assigning to a reference is the same as assigning to the address that it points to, not to the pointer:

```
int x = 5;
int& xref = x;
// equivalent to:
int* const xptr = &x;

xref = 10;
// equivalent to:
*xptr = 10;
```